# Error al Ejecutar JSON - type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: android, webservice, recyclerview, jsonobject, jsonarray

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estimados, llevo días tratando de solucionar este problema de llamar datos desde un Web Services, pero me arroja este error **Wat categorias_prod of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray**, alguien de buen corazón que me ayude a solucionar este problema

Aquí llamo a mi RecyclerView

```
requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        lista_servicios = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerViewPeluqueria = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.RecyclerPeluqueriaID);
        recyclerViewPeluqueria.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerViewPeluqueria.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(),2));
        adapter = new AdaptadorPeluqueria(lista_servicios,context);
        recyclerViewPeluqueria.setAdapter(adapter);
        WEB_SERVICES_SERVICIOS();
```

Este es mi metodo Web Services

```
private void WEB_SERVICES_SERVICIOS() {
        String URL_SERVICIOS_PELUQUERIA ="http://192.168.64.2/raselapp/app/Controllers/listar.php?func=liscat_prod";
        final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_SERVICIOS_PELUQUERIA,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response); //.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", "")
                            String result = jsonObject.getString("result");
                            if(result.equals("success")){

                                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("categorias_prod");

                                for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                    lista_servicios.add(new PeluqueriaDAO(
                                            jsonObject1.getString("descripcion"),
                                            jsonObject1.getInt("precio"),
                                            jsonObject1.getDouble("cod_imagen")));
                                }
                                adapter = new AdaptadorPeluqueria(lista_servicios,context);
                                recyclerViewPeluqueria.setAdapter(adapter);
                            }
                        }catch (JSONException error){
                            error.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toasty.error(context, error.getMessage(),Toasty.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        });

        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

No se que andará mal, algunos comentarios de otros compañeros dicen que el JSON esta mal, o que no puedo convertir un JSONObject a Array, eso me tiene muy confundido

este es mi JSON que me devuelve el .php

```
{"result":"success","categorias_prod":"[{\"cod_producto\":\"1\",\"descripcion\":\"Lavar y Cepillar\",\"precio\":\"8.5\",\"cod_imagen\":\"1\"},{\"cod_producto\":\"2\",\"descripcion\":\"Lavar y Cortar\",\"precio\":\"7.9\",\"cod_imagen\":\"2\"},{\"cod_producto\":\"3\",\"descripcion\":\"Planchar\",\"precio\":\"6.9\",\"cod_imagen\":\"3\"},{\"cod_producto\":\"4\",\"descripcion\":\"Corte Caballero\",\"precio\":\"7.9\",\"cod_imagen\":\"3\"},{\"cod_producto\":\"5\",\"descripcion\":\"Tinte, Lavar y cepillar\",\"precio\":\"33.9\",\"cod_imagen\":\"5\"},{\"cod_producto\":\"6\",\"descripcion\":\"Mechas, Lavar y cepillar\",\"precio\":\"45.9\",\"cod_imagen\":\"6\"}]"}
```

***ESTE ES MI CODIGO PHP****

```
function listar_categorias_productos($request,$con)
{
    $response= array();
    $query="SELECT p.cod_producto , p.descripcion ,p.precio , p.cod_imagen
            FROM tb_productos p,tb_imagenes i,tb_categorias c
            WHERE p.cod_imagen=i.cod_imagen AND p.estado='a' and p.cod_categoria=c.cod_categoria
            AND p.cod_categoria = 1"; 

     if(isset($request['cod_categoria'])){
        $query = $query." AND p.cod_categoria = '".$request['cod_categoria']."'";
     }
    $resul=mysqli_query($con,$query);   
    if(mysqli_num_rows($resul)>0)
    { 
        $response["result"]="success";
        $categorias_prod_array = array();
        while($res=(mysqli_fetch_assoc($resul)))
        {
            $categorias_prod_array[]=$res;  
        }
        $response["categorias_prod"]=json_encode($categorias_prod_array);
    }

    return $response;
}
```

***en este archivo .php llamo a esa funcion***

```
<?php

include("../configureApp/configureGeneral.php");
include("../modules/producto.php");
session_start();
$func = $request['func'];

switch($func){

 //son mas cases, lo simplifique
     //producto.php
     case "liscat_prod":
        $listar=listar_categorias_productos($request,$con); 
        echo json_encode($listar);
    break;

    default:
    echo "Por favor elija una funci&oacute;n";
}

?>
```

el json lo imprimo desde otra archivo que donde llamo a la función

Comment: No tiene sentido todo lo que haces dentro del `while`, para datos que van a ser consumidos en una aplicación no necesitas aplicar `html_entity_decode`, a lo sumo, puedes poner un `header` donde mandas el dato definitivo (tampoco lo veo, porque muestras una función, no el contexto que devuelve los datos a la App. Para simplificar, puedes hacer lo siguiente: ...

Comment: 1. Declaras esto fuera del `while`: **`$categorias_prod_array=array();`** 2. Cambias el método de lectura: `while($res=(mysqli_fetch_assoc($resul)))` 3. Y luego, dentro del `while` pones **simplemente esto**, sin más rollos: **`$categorias_prod_array[]=$res;`**.  Al cambiar a `mysqli_fetch_assoc` nos permitirá obtener ya en `$res` cada valor asociado a su nombre de columna, no hay que ponerrrlo otra vez y además aplicando entidades y demás historias. Así debería mejorar la cosa, si no funciona me posteas  cómo viene ahora el JSON y muestra la parte donde lo estás emitiendo a la App.

Comment: ¿Leíste los dos comentarios más arriba? ¿Aplicaste lo sugerido allí? Por favor pulsa en [edit]  y agrega al final de la pregunta la nueva versión delcódigo PHP así como el JSON que estás recibiendo ahora. Así mismo, agrega la parte de PHP donde mandas los datos a la APP.

Comment: Estimado, aplique todo lo que usted que me dijo, ya modifique el contenido, la imagebn tambien. Disculpe.

Comment: Ten en cuenta los dos pasos que te dije en la respuesta: 1. Validar; 2. Saber analizar el JSON. Para validar imprime un `Log` de `response` cópialo y pégalo en la web que te indiqué para ver si el JSON es válido realmente y luego analízalo. Por algún motivo en vez de un JSONArray te lo sigue creando como un String. Otra cosa que te pedí que mostraras y no has hecho es la parte donde llamas a `listar_categorias_productos` y emites su respuesta a la App.

Comment: Estimado, ya modifique la pregunta, probe el JSOn que me devuelve el Log y si es valido

Comment: [{"cod_producto":"1","descripcion":"Lavar y Cepillar","precio":"8.5","cod_imagen":"1"},{"cod_producto":"2","descripcion":"Lavar y Cortar","precio":"7.9","cod_imagen":"2"},{"cod_producto":"3","descripcion":"Planchar","precio":"6.9","cod_imagen":"3"},{"cod_producto":"4","descripcion":"Corte Caballero","precio":"7.9","cod_imagen":"3"},{"cod_producto":"5","descripcion":"Tinte, Lavar y cepillar","precio":"33.9","cod_imagen":"5"},{"cod_producto":"6","descripcion":"Mechas, Lavar y cepillar","precio":"45.9","cod_imagen":"6"}]

Comment: Pero ese no es el JSON original, ahí falta la clave `categorias_prod` que sería la que contendría el array de objetos JSON que muestras en tu comentario anterior. Por otra parte, tienes duplicidad de `json_encode`, lo usas en el return de `listar_categorias_productos` y en el `case`. Deberías usarlo una sola vez, generalmente se usaría en el punto final donde retornas la respuesta a la App. Tienes que organizar bien tu código, sino te estará dando problemas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Tu problema es el JSON: es válido pero no coherente

El problema es que el servidor no está generando un JSON con la estructura que esperas.

Te recomiendo que revises tu JSON en [este sitio on line](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com). Puedes copiarlo y pegarlo allí y luego validar.

Aunque el mismo es *válido* **teóricamente** no está formado como debería estarlo, porque  en ese JSON en la clave `categorias_prod` **hay una cadena** no un `JSONArray` que es lo que debería haber para leer el objeto como de hecho se ve que intentas hacerlo, aunque de una manera errónea, como explicará en el punto 3.

Esta es una imagen del JSON que expones en tu pregunta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### 2. Se necesita un JSON válido Y coherente

El JSON que tendría una estructura conforme al código que muestras en tu pregunta, sería este:

```
{
   "result":"success",
   "categorias_prod":[
      {
         "cod_producto":"1",
         "descripcion":"Lavar y Cepillar",
         "precio":"8.5",
         "cod_imagen":"1"
      },
      {
         "cod_producto":"2",
         "descripcion":"Lavar y Cortar",
         "precio":"7.9",
         "cod_imagen":"2"
      },
      {
         "cod_producto":"3",
         "descripcion":"Planchar",
         "precio":"6.9",
         "cod_imagen":"3"
      },
      {
         "cod_producto":"4",
         "descripcion":"Corte Caballero",
         "precio":"7.9",
         "cod_imagen":"3"
      },
      {
         "cod_producto":"5",
         "descripcion":"Tinte, Lavar y cepillar",
         "precio":"33.9",
         "cod_imagen":"5"
      },
      {
         "cod_producto":"6",
         "descripcion":"Mechas, Lavar y cepillar",
         "precio":"45.9",
         "cod_imagen":"6"
      }
   ]
}
```

Si observas bien, hay dos diferencias fundamentales con respecto al anterior:

1. La clave `categorias_prod` no empieza por *comilla corche*, sino **sólo por corchete**. Es eso y no otra cosa lo que implica en la notación JSON que se trata de un `JSONArray`
2. No hay carácteres de escape (`\`). El JSON de la imagen valida a pesar de esos caracteres porque todo dentro es tratado como una cadena sin más, pero a la hora de expresar un `JSONArray` con varios `JSONObject` dentro, esa notación es inválida.

### 3. Solución

Primeramente, debes trabajar tu código de servidor para que te devuelva un JSON válido y coherente parecido al que se muestra en (2). Donde la clave `categorias_prod` sea realmente un `JSONArray`. En ese código debes evitar también a toda costa los carácteres de escape `\`. Desde PHP es relativamente fácil producir un JSON limpio. Quizá no estés usando allí la forma más adecuada para devolver tus datos a la aplicación.

Luego, debes dar coherencia a tu código Android. Si describimos tu JSON podemos decir que ***hay una clave llamada `categorias_prod` que contiene un `JSONArray` con varios `JSONObject` dentro***. Con esa descripción del JSON ¡ya sabemos lo que hay que hacer!. Hay que extraer el `JSONArray` que hay dentro de la clave `categorias_prod` y leer los objetos que hay dentro de él.

El código en Android debería quedar así:

```
                    try {
                        //Aquí obtienes el objeto JSON general
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        //Dentro de él hay una clave llamada result: OK
                        String result = jsonObject.getString("result");

                        if(result.equals("success")){
                            /*
                                Esto era erróneo en tu código: 
                                TIENES QUE BUSCAR EL JSONARRAY EN LA CLAVE categorias_prod
                                no en response, que era sólo la cadena que ya convertiste
                                a JSONObject y que guardaste en la variable jsonObject
                                en lo adelante debes usar esa variable para obtener las
                                parte de tu objeto JSON...
                                También lo movemos de sito por lógica:
                                Si no se cumple el if no tendría sentido tratar de obtener esto
                            */
                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("categorias_prod");

                            for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                                JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                lista_servicios.add(new PeluqueriaDAO(
                                        jsonObject1.getString("descripcion"),
                                        jsonObject1.getInt("precio"),
                                        jsonObject1.getDouble("cod_imagen")));
                            }
```

### 4. Claves muy sencillas para entender JSON

JSON es un formato muy simple y ligero, por eso se ha extendido en casi todos los servicios web. Te doy algunas claves para que no te vuelvas loco cuando un JSON falle:

- **Validar siempre** tu JSON y analizarlo (usando la herramienta on line cuyo enlace ya tienes al principio de esta respuesta). Hay otras, pero esta es de las mejores, no sólo te valida, sino que te permite ver la estructura del objeto, agruparlo o desagruparlo para **analizarlo** y comprender su estructura.
- **Saber analizar** un JSON. Es muy simple: todo lo que empieza por `[` es un JSON Array, y dentro de ese array pueden haber cadenas, números, booleanos, y/o otros objetos JSON. Los objetos JSON empiezan por `{` siempre. Se trate del objeto global, se trate de sub-ohjetos que éste contenga. Y el objeto global puede ser tanto un JSON array (si empieza por`[`) como un JSON object (si empieza por `{`. Comprendiendo eso, sabrás encontrar siempre dónde está la dificultad cuando un código falle, revisando la forma en que está estructurado el JSON y la forma en que lo estás leyendo.

  Esto es muy importante saberlo, porque a la hora de obtener cada dato, deberás usar el método adecuado según el tipo de dato que haya en la clave a la que quieres acceder. Si analizamos por ejemplo unos de los objetos JSON que hay dentro del array:

  ```
    {
       "cod_producto":"1",
       "descripcion":"Lavar y Cepillar",
       "precio":"8.5",
       "cod_imagen":"1"
    },
  ```

  Vemos una situación **grave** con respecto a tu código ya que, para obtener el valor de `precio` haces esto:

  ```
      jsonObject1.getInt("precio")
  ```

  Y para obtener el valor de `cod_imagen` haces esto:

  ```
      jsonObject1.getDouble("cod_imagen")
  ```

  Para el primer caso estás usando el método `getInt`,  y para el segundo caso estás usando el método `getDouble`. **PEEEEERO** como ya dijimos antes, analizando en JSON, en la clave `precio`  no hay un entero ni en la clave `cod_imagen` hay un double... También en eso debes dar coherencia al JSON, poniendo los valores así:

  ```
    {
       "cod_producto":"1",
       "descripcion":"Lavar y Cepillar",
       "precio":8.5,
       "cod_imagen":1
    },
  ```

  ¿Cuál es la diferencia? ¡Que no hay comillas rodeando los valores. Cuando hay comillas se reconoce como una cadena, y el método a usar en esos casos sería `getString`. Lo mismo ocurrirá con `cod_producto` si intentas obtenerlo con `getInt()`

Comment: Estimado A. Cedano, Muchisimas Gracias por responder y explicarme detalladamente acerca de los JSON, con lo que usted me explico hice los cambios respectivos en mi codigo ya no me aparece ese error, me sale esto: "categorias_prod of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSOArray", esto ya me esta volviendo loco :(

Comment: @TonyOrmaza está ocurriendo justo lo que te he explicado. El mensaje de error indica que el JSON que se produce tiene en `categorias_prod` un `String` (o sea una cadena), no un `JSONArray`.  Tienes que revisar qué está ocurriendo en el servidor. Te propongo que agregues a la pregunta el código PHP que crea el JSON, no estás creando bien el objeto y de ahí el problema. Ahora, viendo más de cerca la cosa, tendrás problemas también aquí por ejemplo: `jsonObject1.getDouble("cod_imagen")` porque en la clave `cod_imagen` pasa lo mismo, no tienes un valor del tipo `Double` realmente, sino `String`.

Comment: @TonyOrmaza revisa los comentarios que te hice en la pregunta.